# How can we use Apache POI library for .xls file in iOS

Tags: ios, edit, xls, read-write

I want to read, write and edit .xls files in iOS, 
There are some libraries like JXSL(for writing) and DHXLS (for reading),
But I want to edit the existing file.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Any one here ?.